# Shared memory synchronization with semaphores

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory

For homework I need to use IPC. I write some code for shared memory but it does not work as I want. I want server process to run before client. What I am doing wrong? How to fix it?

```
//main.cpp
#include "stockexchangeserver.h"
#include "stockexchangeclient.h"
#include <semaphore.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   StockExchangeServer server;
   StockExchangeClient client;
   pid_t   pid;
   sem_t sem;
   int pshared = 1;
   unsigned int value = 0;
   sem_init(&sem,pshared,value);

   if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
       std::cout<<"fork error\n";
    } else if (pid > 0) {
       sem_wait(&sem);
       client.start2();
       sem_post(&sem);
    } else {
       server.start2();
       sem_post(&sem);
    }
   return 0;
}

   //stockexchangeclient.cpp
   void StockExchangeClient::start2() {
    int sharedMemoryId;
    key_t key;
    int *shm;
    key = 6000;

    if((sharedMemoryId = shmget(key,sizeof(int),0666)) < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Shared memory create error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else{}

    if((shm = (int *)shmat(sharedMemoryId,NULL,0)) == (int *)-1) {
        std::cout<<"Shared memory attach error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else{}
    *shm = 1;
    exit(0);
}

//stockexchangeserver.cpp
void StockExchangeServer::start2()
{
    int sharedMemoryId;
    key_t key;
    int *shm;
    key = 6000;

    if((sharedMemoryId = shmget(key,sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Shared memory create error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else{}
    if((shm = (int *)shmat(sharedMemoryId,NULL,0)) == (int *)-1) {
        std::cout<<"Shared memory attach error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else{}
   *shm = 0;
    while(*shm == 0) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    std::cout<<"Shared memory succeded\n";
}
```

Comment: You can't control which process runs first. So you need to make your code do the right thing either way. Also, you need to use some kind of synchronization or the compiler is free to optimize away the accesses to `*shm`, resulting in the `while` loop being endless.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Your observation is precise. But in this particular case, even without optimization, the `while` loop is indeed endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and in fact server process is running first ( `StockExchangeServer::start2` ) But the problem is in

```
while(*shm == 0) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is resulting in an infinite loop and you are not giving an opportunity to `StockExchangeClient::start2()` to change `*shm` as parent is waiting indefinitely at `sem_wait` as the child never executed `sem_post`

Instead can do a `sem_post` before entering the loop in `StockExchangeServer::start2` so that you release the parent from its `sem_wait`. For this you need to send `&sem` to `StockExchangeServer::start2`. May be by changing its prototype into something like `StockExchangeServer::start2( sem_t *sem )`.

But as `sem` is an **unnamed semaphore**, and 2 copies exist, one in parent and one in child, and if you want both parent and child to use it, you need to create it in a shared memory region using `shmget` and then access it across processes. If you don't want all this pain, you can switch to **named semaphores** which can be even accessed by unrelated processes. **In short, unnamed semaphores are generally used for threads ( as threads share data )and named semaphores for processes.**

Also as observed by David Schwartz in comments make sure to prevent unintended optimization of the `while` loop. Say for example, print out the value of `shm` before the loop.

Comment: passing sem_t pointer to both start functions is a very good idea but it does not work with unnamed semaphores so I changed unnamed semaphore with named one and it works. Just update your answer and advice to use named semaphores because forked processes synchronize with them. The result will be a good answer